Upgrading Xcode version from 15.2 to {15.3-15.4} results in Azure DevOps pipeline simulator architecture error
Description
We've been running our unit and snapshot tests through our Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline for a while now, all going well. Now we decided to upgrade our current settings to the new runner, xcode version and simulator.
Working settings before upgrade:
- name: runnerImage
  value: 'macOS-13'
- name: XcodeVersion
  value: 'Xcode_15.2.app'
- name: iOSSimulator
  value: 'iPhone 15 Pro,OS=17.2'

Failing settings after upgrade:
- name: runnerImage
  value: 'macOS-14'
- name: XcodeVersion
  value: 'Xcode_15.4.app'
- name: iOSSimulator
  value: 'iPhone 15 Pro,OS=17.5'

Error message
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project  with scheme .: Cannot test target Tests on iPhone 15 Pro: Tests does not support any of iPhone 15 Pro’s architectures: x86_64.
With some trial and error on the steps between this upgrade, we managed to have successful tests using macOS-14 and iOSSimulator iPhone 15 Pro,OS=17.5. However, it seems the Xcode version is causing the error. Using macOS-14 and iPhone 15 Pro,OS=17.5, combined with Xcode_15.2.app, we get successful tests. Using Xcode_15.3.app or Xcode15.4.app, we get above error message.
To be complete: Our builds on release are succeeding. Our tests on debug are failing. We use xcodegen to generate our project. Based on intensive google search I found some hints towards some build settings that could be changed, like setting Architectures to x86_64 for Debug (though that cannot be the option since we also need to debug on devices instead of just simulator) or setting Build Active Architectures Only to No, so x86_64 would also be embedded in the build.
Looking for a fix when this ends up being a bug, or some hints to resolve this failed tests on Azure DevOps.
Expected behavior
Tests succeeding like they did on Xcode_15.2.app, where the x86_64 architecture for iOS Simulator is not an issue.
Actual behavior
Tests are failing on Xcode_15.3.app and Xcode_15.4.app, where the x86_64 architecture for iOS Simulator is an issue.
Repro steps

Setup an Azure DevOps Pipeline
Configure a job to use the vmImage: macOS-14 from the pool
Setup xcode-select to use a specific xcode version (to succeed: Xcode_15.2.app -- to fail either: Xcode_15.3.app or Xcode_15.4.app
Configure an Xcode@5 task with actions: test, scheme: Debug and destinationPlatform: iPhone 15 Pro,OS=17.5
Run the pipeline


Since it only fails with Xcode_15.3.app and Xcode_15.4.app but works with Xcode_15.2.app, it seems an issue from your project itself but not from DevOps. It's recommended to try with Xcode_15.3(4) on local macOS to check if it works.  Please check similar link.

@Hutjepower did you solve this issue?

@tagy22 Unfortunately not. Locally on ARM device and Xcode 15.4 as wade zhou suggested shows we don't have issues. Since we're re-considering our CI/CD, it doesn't have priority to investigate further for now, though still interested in a solution which I will post when we find it.
